# How to print crop marks with KOMA-Script class scrbook

Tags: koma-script, crop, cropmarks

I want to print crop marks for a format smaller than a4 which is printed on a4 stock.
I use KOMA-Script class `scrbook` and add `geometry` and `crop` packages - nothing happens. 
How can I have crop marks printed around the text so I can judge the layout?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      
    128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[axes,cross,pdftex,center]{crop}

\begin{document}

some text 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add option `a4` to tell package `crop` to use paper a4 to show crop informations and the little book.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{%
  paper=128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    BCOR=8mm,twoside,
    headinclude=false, footinclude=false, 
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[%
  a4, % <===============================================================
  axes,cross,pdftex,center
]{crop}

\begin{document}

some text 

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you! I got confused with thinking that the a4 refers to the size of desired size, not the paper size used!